# SharePoint List behaving Weird after migration

Tags: sharepoint-2013

Recently we migrated 2013 sites to office 365 using metalogix tool, in one of the site Task list is migrated with all content but the date which is displaying in due date column is one day ahead of the date in source site

Ex: due date is 02/03/2017 in source but in target it is 03/03/2017

are there any teams which faced similar kind of issue??
what might be the fix for this issue??

Answer (score 0):

You have migrated your SP 2013 sites to O365. Your SP 2013 uses your local timezone and O365 uses its timezone. When you migrate SP2013 to O365, it changes the DateTime value(in your local timezone) to O365 timezone. Thats the reason for 1 day ahead.

Answer (score 0):

We're experiencing a similar issue now migrating from a SP 2007 on prem to a SP 2013 on prem. In one list, the dates are "1/01/1900" but the migration fails with Metalogix reporting that "1899-12-31T15:00:00.0000000Z" is an invalid date for those exact fields.

Not sure why at the moment as both servers appear to be set in the same time zone with the same locale.

**UPDATE:** This is happening on our servers because the SP2007 is set to GMT time whereas the SP2013 is set to UTC time. A default time value in a date/time field entered when the user cannot enter a time component is 12am. So during the migration daylight savings is/isn't taken into account on one of the servers. We've pushed those particular records one day ahead -> when they get migrated they fall back to 01/01/1900 11:00pm -> all we care about is the date so they come across.